# Azure Function Triggered by IoT Hub event - the messaging entity could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

When developing Azure Function thru Class Library approach (local development) I came across issue when using Even Hub compatible endpoint of IoTHub for triggering my function. This is set thru IoTHubTrigger attribute:

```
 [FunctionName("IoTHubMessageProcessor")]
 public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events",  Connection= "IoTHubReceiveEventsConnectionEndpoint")]EventData message, ILogger log)
```

When using provided connection string and messages/events endpoint I received error stating that "messaging entity could not be found".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to alter the connection string and include also **Event Hub compatible name in connection string as an entity path** so it looks like this:

```
Endpoint=sb://<Event hub-compatible endpoint>.servicebus.windows.net/;EntityPath=<Event Hub compatible name>;SharedAccessKeyName=<keyName>;SharedAccessKey=<key>"
```